# Android CoordinatorLayout, Scrolling Activity template all layout is flying away

Tags: android, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout

**TL;DR**
I'd like to have the possibility to hide/show Appbar content by gestures on Appbar itself as in Android Studio's
`Scrolling Activity` template. But need to prevent weird effect described below.

**DETAILS**
1.Open Android Studio 2.0 and start new Android Studio project, name it ScrollingActivity, choose Phone and Tablet, API 9. Choose `Scrolling Activity` template. Leave all the rest default.
2.Run Activity on Android Lollipop 5.1.1. In my case it was MS VS Emulator.
3.Scroll text to its very top so that Appbar is fully expanded (and FAB is visible).

4.Note now you can scroll layout by gestures applied on Appbar itself, expanding in to full height `180dp` or collapsing to toolbar only.

Cool. I want it in my app.

5.But playing with gestures on Appbar I've managed to make *all layout but FAB totally disappear* :( Weird.
Well, it will be back in a minute, but definetly I don't want it in my app.

To get some more details let's add a listener to the Appbar

```
    // Track how AppBarLayout is flying
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            Log.d ("OffsetChangedListener", "appBarLayout goes to=" + verticalOffset );
        }
    });
```

Normally offset is within (-273, 0) on my XXHDPI device. But suddenly after some flinging on Appbar my logcat shows
that Appbar went to long trip into outerspace:

```
06-02 11:37:13.059 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-273
06-02 11:37:15.523 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-186
06-02 11:37:15.529 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=311
06-02 11:37:15.563 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=3833
06-02 11:37:15.564 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=0
06-02 11:37:15.638 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=11594
06-02 11:37:15.690 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=16968
06-02 11:37:15.710 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=19137
...
06-02 11:38:07.242 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=2684733
06-02 11:38:07.343 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-536483
...
06-02 11:38:29.983 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-796
06-02 11:38:30.066 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-563
06-02 11:38:30.125 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-422
06-02 11:38:30.202 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-268
06-02 11:38:30.253 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-185
06-02 11:38:30.385 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=-41
06-02 11:38:30.587 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=0
06-02 11:38:30.588 18116-18116/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OffsetChangedListener: appBarLayout goes to=0
```

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Really don't know whether it IS an answer, but this workaround worked for me

1. Add dummy non-scrollable view just after `AppBarLayout`, so that activity layout looks like

   ```
   android:background="#00FF00">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/app_bar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
           android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
           app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
               app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

       </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <!-- Workaround view-->
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="They'll be back"
       android:id="@+id/dummy"/>

   <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
       app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
       app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
   ```
2. Add some view tackling in appbar's  `OnOffsetChangedListener`

public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    // Track how AppBarLayout is flying
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    final View vDummy = findViewById(R.id.dummy);
    final int maxHeight = appBarLayout.getLayoutParams().height; //was set explicitly in XML
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            Log.d("OCL", "appBarLayout goes to=" + verticalOffset);
            vDummy.setVisibility(
                          (verticalOffset >=-maxHeight && verticalOffset<=0)
                          ? View.GONE
                          : View.VISIBLE
            );
        }
    });

}
```

I still can launch AppBar into outer space but it returns very quickly

```
06-06 17:46:06.510 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=0
06-06 17:46:06.558 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=0
06-06 17:46:07.525 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-20
06-06 17:46:07.562 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-57
06-06 17:46:07.612 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-114
06-06 17:46:07.641 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-39239
06-06 17:46:07.641 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-202
06-06 17:46:07.668 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-81278
06-06 17:46:07.669 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-202
06-06 17:46:07.703 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-133824
06-06 17:46:07.704 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-202
06-06 17:46:07.731 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-174358
06-06 17:46:07.731 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-202
06-06 17:46:07.865 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-377007
06-06 17:46:07.866 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-202
06-06 17:46:07.885 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-407026
06-06 17:46:07.886 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-202
06-06 17:46:07.921 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-162
06-06 17:46:07.923 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-161
06-06 17:46:07.923 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-161
06-06 17:46:07.969 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-104
06-06 17:46:08.015 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-61
06-06 17:46:08.067 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-29
06-06 17:46:08.070 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-29
06-06 17:46:08.105 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=-12
06-06 17:46:08.256 13077-13077/com.example.scrollingactivity D/OCL: appBarLayout goes to=0
```